# Using Pdf in android app with protection?

Tags: android, file, pdf

I am working on an app which downloads the pdf from the server and stores it. Then I use another application like repligo reader to read the pdf from my app.

I wanted to know that is there any way that the pdf files could be stored in a way that no other application could read the file . The file is read only when it is used from my app.
Is there any way?Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As per my knowledge) I think for this you have to store your downloaded pdf file in application's internal package,
`/data/data/<package_name>files`, and you have to read this file through **third party pdf readers**. For this you have to store this file with permission as `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` so pdf file is stored in your application's package and you can read it with third party pdf reader. Also its placed in internal storage so not other application can easily access it (except root device).

The code for write files,

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(pdfFileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(pdfAsBytes);
fos.close();
```

**EDIT:**

To view PDF file I used,

```
File file = new File("/data/data/<package_Name>/files/pdffile");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try
{
  startActivity(pdfIntent);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Log.e("Activity Not Found Exception",e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the pdf reader shows a black screen and finishes.Do you have any idea what else I should try

Comment: This works fine in my case, I downloaded pdf file store in files directory using above code then using intent display it in AdobePdfReader.